# My Activity Class turn into an xml file

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, arrays

i recently just finished my app for my school project before i go to sleep but i didn't build it yet for i thought that i will still put some changes in it the next morning then when my classmate ask me for help for their project i opened my android studio and this is what happens to my activity where all the codes that i made is in there i already try to check on the local history but their nothing shown. anyone could help me

```js
<application>
  <component name="StatisticsApplicationUsages">
    <group name="run-configuration-type">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="AndroidRunConfigurationType" collectionTime="1508377527412" />
    </group>
    <group name="frameworks">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="android-gradle,java-gradle,android" collectionTime="1508377527256" />
    </group>
    <group name="run-configuration-type-temp">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="AndroidRunConfigurationType" collectionTime="1508377527412" />
    </group>
    <group name="file-type">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="Properties,Groovy,JAVA,ProGuard File,ARCHIVE,PLAIN_TEXT,UNKNOWN,Images,IDEA_MODULE,XML" collectionTime="1508377535538" />
    </group>
    <group name="images.ide.background">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="frame=0,editor=0" collectionTime="1508377539101" />
    </group>
    <group name="module type">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="JAVA_MODULE" collectionTime="1508377527318" />
    </group>
    <group name="Git">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="config.ssh.enabled,config.repo.sync.NOT_DECIDED,config.warn.about.detached.enabled,config.save.policy.STASH,config.push.autoupdate.disabled,config.force.push.enabled,config.push.update.all.roots.enabled,config.warn.about.crlf.enabled,config.update.type.BRANCH_DEFAULT,config.cherry-pick.autocommit.disabled" collectionTime="1508377540992" />
    </group>
    <group name="language-level">
      <project id="MoniDroid" values="JDK_1_7" collectionTime="1508377540570" />
    </group>
  </component>
  <component name="UsageTrigger">
    <counts>
      <entry feature="CreateFile.CreateFileAction" count="4" />
      <entry feature="execute.AndroidRunConfigurationType.Debug" count="2" />
      <entry feature="execute.AndroidRunConfigurationType.Run" count="1451" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Appearance" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Plugins" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ideaapp.started" count="140" />
      <entry feature="terminal.win" count="1" />
      <entry feature="tips.of.the.day.next" count="20" />
      <entry feature="tips.of.the.day.prev" count="14" />
      <entry feature="welcome.screen.WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject" count="2" />
    </counts>
  </component>
</application>
```

Comment: is this your mainActivity code ?

Comment: yes it is it contains all my hardwork for 1 month and i really need some help i dont know how to retrieve it since im just new in making apps

Comment: do you have any backups of your project? and Where did you create your project before opening it to android studio?

Comment: that was my big mistake and i hate my self for it i forgot to make some backups. i create a folder for its location

Answer (score 2):

You can get your code back from local history of Android Studio. You need to follow below steps.

1) Launch Android Studio and open the file (It can be your activity or xml code file)

2) Click on VCS

3) Go to Local History from the menu

4) And select Show local history

5) No 5th step :)

Get your code from history

Comment: already did that but it only shows the changes that i did after this happens