# Android files (Java and XML) being replaced by weird XML

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

I encountered a bizarre issue while using Android Studio (v2.3.3, built on 2017-06-06). One of my Java files was replaced with unrelated XML that seemed to be generated by Android Studio. I don't think I did anything to trigger it. A second Java file suffered the same fate soon afterwards, once again, with no discernible cause.

Thankfully I had just ZIPed up a copy of the source code so I deleted the files and replaced them. I don't have an exact copy of the weird code, but this code I found at [git.moeryn.com](https://git.moeryn.com/Moeryn/dotfiles/blob/eb437be230c96169c2ebd773cdf67d6301c76c55/IntelliJ/idea/config/options/statistics.application.usages.xml) is pretty close to what I saw:

```
<application>
  <component name="UsageTrigger">
    <counts>
      <entry feature="CreateFile.CreateFileAction" count="1" />
      <entry feature="JSDebugConfig.Debug.browser-default.preferredBrowser-null.no_mappings" count="6" />
      <entry feature="OpenInBrowser.Opera" count="1" />
      <entry feature="execute.Application.Coverage" count="1" />
      <entry feature="execute.Application.Debug" count="1" />
      <entry feature="execute.Application.Run" count="15" />
      <entry feature="execute.GWT.ConfigurationType.Debug" count="12" />
      <entry feature="execute.GWT.ConfigurationType.Run" count="18" />
      <entry feature="execute.GroovyScriptRunConfiguration.Debug" count="1" />
      <entry feature="execute.GroovyScriptRunConfiguration.Run" count="9" />
      <entry feature="execute.JUnit.Coverage" count="4" />
      <entry feature="execute.JUnit.Run" count="86" />
      <entry feature="execute.JavascriptDebugType.Debug" count="6" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Appearance" count="4" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Colors_&amp;_Fonts" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Console_Font" count="4" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Font" count="4" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.General" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Gerrit" count="4" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Java" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Keymap" count="12" />
      <entry feature="ide.settings.Vim_Emulation" count="2" />
      <entry feature="idea.caches.invalidated" count="1" />
      <entry feature="ideaapp.started" count="28" />
      <entry feature="terminal.linux" count="2" />
      <entry feature="uml.ShowDiagram.JAVA" count="1" />
      <entry feature="welcome.screen.WelcomeScreen.Configure" count="1" />
      <entry feature="welcome.screen.WelcomeScreen.CreateNewProject" count="2" />
    </counts>
  </component>
</application>
```

I found somebody on StackOverflow who encountered a similar problem last week: [My Activity Class turn into an xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870965/my-activity-class-turn-into-an-xml-file), however, there was no resolution or explanation of what happened. I found another instance of someone encountering the same problem here: [Android Studio wrong load a source file](http://android.wekeepcoding.com/article/12376890/Android+Studio+wrong+load+a+source+file)

Now it has happened to me a third time - this time it affected an XML file in res/anim. This is really puzzling (and worrisome since I am now paranoid it'll happen again). Oddly enough, the file contents are cut off midway through a tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="AnalysisUIOptions">
    <option name="SCOPE_TYPE" value="3" />
  </component>
  <component name="AndroidLayouts">
    <shared>
      <config>
        <devices>
          <device id="Nexus 6" />
          <device id="pixel" />
          <device id="Nexus 4" />
          <device id="tv_720p" />
          <device id="tv_1080p" />
          <device id="wear_round_chin_320_290" />
          <device id="Galaxy Nexus" />
          <device id="Nexus One" />
        </devices>
      </config>
    </shared>
  </component>
  <component name="AndroidLogFilters">
    <option name="TOOL_WINDOW_LOG_LEVEL" value="verbose" />
    <option name="TOOL_WINDOW_CONFIGURED_FILTER" value="Show only selected application" />
  </component>
  <component name="BookmarkManager">
    <bookmar
```

#### **Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any idea what might be causing it?**

---

It happened a few more times when I opened XML files. **transition__dialog__slide_out_to_right.xml** was replaced with the beginning of my FlagView.java class that I was working on earlier (*note that the Java file wasn't open at the time, it had been 2+ hours since I'd been editing it, and this code wasn't in my clipboard*):

```
package co.company.app.views;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.
```

**transition__dialog__slide_in_from_right.xml** got replaced with this partial XML:

```
<application>
  <component name="UsageTrigger">
    <counts>
      <entry feature="CreateFile.CreateFileAction" count="2" />
      <entry feature="execute.AndroidRunConfigurationType.Debug" count="14" />
      <entry feature="execute.AndroidRunConfigurationType.Run" count="2237" />
      <entry feature="execute.GradleRunCon
```

The other transition anim files opened normally. However, another file in **res/anim** got replaced with most of my Canadian flag drawable XML file:

```
<!-- Canadian flag -->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="1000.0"
        android:viewportHeight="500.0">

    <!-- Background red rectangle -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#f00"
        android:pathData="M 0,0  L 1000,0  L 1000,500  L 0,500"
        />

    <!-- Center white square -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M250,0  H750  V500  H250"
        />

    <!-- Maple leaf -->
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:pathData=
            "
            M 499.992280,  46.87500
              -34.113120,  63.62529
            c  -3.870860,   6.91501
              -10.806270,   6.27363
              -17.741690,   2.41138
            l -24.696990, -12.78858
               18.407050,  97.72711
            c   3.870860,  17.85419
               -8.548590,  17.85419
               -14.67765,  10.13435
            l -43.101050, -48.25099
               -6.997380,  24.50300
            c  -0.806920,   3.21777
               -4.354810,   6.59744
               -9.677480,   5.79261
            l -54.501770, -11.45912
               14.315240,  52.04475
            c   3.064510,  11.58054
                5.454900,  16.37528
                -3.09375,  19.42959
            l -19.426190,   9.13025
               93.821270,  76.20838
            c   3.713500,   2.88151
                5.589710,   8.06700
                4.267680,  12.76210
            l  -8.211360,  26.94707   
            c  32.304050,  -3.72371
               61.248980,  -9.32594
               93.569390, -12.77619
                2.853230,  -0.30459
                7.629880,   4.40408
                7.610290,   7.71058
            l  -4.280240,  98.72342
               15.706390,   0
               -2.472370,
```

**Very bizarre...**

---

I closed Android Studio, and when I reopened it, it was using the default light theme instead of my dark theme. A list of errors appeared on the right side of the screen. I closed the application and reopened it. This time I got a popup saying Start Failed:

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.psi.PsiDocumentManager'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:285)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$getDefaultProject$2(ProjectManagerImpl.java:280)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.getDefaultProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:277)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateManager.getDefaultInstance(FileTemplateManager.java:67)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.setUpNewProjectActions(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:270)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidStudioInitializer.run(AndroidStudioInitializer.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeLater(LaterInvocator.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ModalityInvokatorImpl.invokeLater(ModalityInvokatorImpl.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeLater(ApplicationImpl.java:379)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeLater(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeLater(ApplicationImpl.java:364)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.<init>(DocumentCommitThread.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ImmutablePicoContainerProxyFactory.invoke(ImmutablePicoContainerProxyFactory.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.getComponentInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:495)
    ... 54 more
```

Something seems to have gone terribly wrong with Android Studio...

Comment: which version of android studio?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.3.3, built on 2017-06-06. I tried Android Studio v3 a few months ago and encountered some issues, so I've been sticking with v2.3, but now that v3 has been officially released, it may be time for me to make the switch.

Comment: This has been happening to me lately with Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: @Amber Maybe try deleting this folder:
C:\Users\my_user_name\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches

As suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't uncover the root cause of the issue, but following Yashasvi's prompt and the fortunate timing of Android Studio v3's release (5 days before my question on [2017-10-25](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html)), I upgraded the software and everything has been working fine since.

Not the most satisfying conclusion to my question, but the my code isn't being screwed up and I'm happy.