# Android Studio 3.2.1 keeps corrupting Java files on weird XML

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

After a random crash on Android Studio, a lot of my code is being opened by Android Studio as if it was an XML or R.class.

[Sample of Corrupted File 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GDNC.png)

[Sample of Corrupted File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab3br.png)

Explaning it better: It does correct itself after a fresh install of Android Studio (any version), and it hasn't happened in 3.1.4, but I'm using features from 3.2. After less than 6h coding, a random crash happens on Android, I report it by the AS and this suddenly happens to many of my files, not allowing me to build it again until I reinstall Android entirely.

I'm running AS as an Administrator, and I do have permission everywhere.
My project is not corrupted nor are my files, since every single fresh install simply brings my code back and I can code until any/a random crash happens, creating this AS/Gradle corruption.

As you can tell, even when "corrupted" on AS, my code is actually fine [when opened with any external editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOyYX.png), so reverting back my Git code is not enough to make me get rid of this problem (I wish).

Some important things I already tried:

- Clear Cache and Restart Android Studio
- Use Android 3.2.1 and 3.3 RC
- Rebuild Project
- Resync with Gradle, FileSystem, etc, etc...
- Clear caches from **/user/.gradle/caches** and from **/user/.AndroidStudio3.3/system/caches**
- Delete .idea and .gradle from the project's folder
- Reinstall Android Studio (also tried with both versions)

I found a related issue here, but the guy simply deleted both of those files. But that's something I can't do, since this is happening with my project files. This related issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058559/android-studio-auto-generated-public-final-class-r-file/53540918).

I also found another 3 or 4 posts, which where never answered with a valid answer and that were "never solved" or were solved by installing a new version of AS. But I'm already trying the Beta and this error/problem persists....

Consider this post a cry for help. This is haunting me in my development in such a way that I simply can't program more than 6 hours before getting this bizarre behavior in each and any newer version of AS.

**References:**

[Related by @Vengat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150/java-and-xml-files-corrupted-by-weird-xml-in-android-studio3-2-1)

[Related by @CanProgram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020914/android-files-java-and-xml-being-replaced-by-weird-xml) (since 2.3.3?)

[Related by @RmGetty Bautista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870965/my-activity-class-turn-into-an-xml-file)

[Related at KeepCoding](https://android.wekeepcoding.com/article/12376890/Android+Studio+wrong+load+a+source+file)

Comment: I was also facing a similar issue not a while ago. Tried all the options you mentioned but nothing worked. I eventually had to delete the existing version of Android studio(including my custom settings) and re-download it again. Then I faced the same issue again. I think the problem is with Android Studio's latest version (3.2.1), I'm now using version 3.1 and everything is working well

Comment: That's so sad.... I also tried 3.3 RC and I faced the same problem... Seems like I'll have to go back to 1.4 again, and stick to it. I really wish this was addressed by Google as soon as possible, since this is a serious Development break.

Comment: Solution for latest android studio https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746941/5773037

Answer (score -1):

Tbh, android studio sucks at that part. If you encounter that problem, then r.i.p to your code.
The way I tried to minimized the chance of getting my file corrupted is by closing the emulator whenever I finished running the program, and also when it works properly, I copy all the files to a notepad just in case something bad happen.
*and yes it happened right when I wanted to show my assignment in front of my lecturer, thanks to notepad I can retrieve it back